# Opposite of String.IsNullOrEmpty() or an alternative way

Tags: asp.net, .net

I wrote this script, that works:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Description))
{
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow2);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow3);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow4);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow5);
}
else if (item.Description.Equals("euro"))
{
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow4);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow5);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow2);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow3);
}
else // I assume that this will always be "euro6" entry
{
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow2);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow3);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow4);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow5);
}
```

but I really don't like it, but since I'm a php programmer, I have no idea how to write it correctly in ASP.NET

The idea is that, if the value `item.Description` is not present or is "euro6", it has one option, but, if the value is "euro", then the other one.
In PHP I would do it like this

```
if ( $description == "euro" ) {
    // first option
} else {
    // second option
}
```

but in .NET if the value is not set I get an error, so I made a bad workaround.

Can I get some assistance to make this the right way?

Comment: You don't need to use `String.Equals` in .NET to compare two strings. The `==` operator is overloaded so it does not only compare references (like in java). It also handles the `null` issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I get an error" is fairly vague - you would get a `NullReferenceException` if you used `item.Description.Equals("euro"))` but this should be fine:

```
if (item.Description == "euro")
{
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow4);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow5);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow2);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow3);
}
else
{
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow2);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow3);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow4);
    tbItemInput.Rows.Add(tbRow5);
}
```

Comment: Won't this generate a notice or something similar if the `item.Description` value is not set at all?

Comment: @Dainis: No, it will be fine. The == operator handles nullity with no problem.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got too much stuck using `Equals()` and didn't even try the most obvious solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Description) || item.Description == "euro6")
{
    // Euro6 or default option
}
else 
{
    // Euro option
}
```

Or even simpler

```
if (item.Description == "euro")
{
    // Euro option
}
else 
{
    // Not euro option(empty or euro6 or whatever)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this kind of code**

```
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Description))   //check for item.Description is not empty and not null
            {
               if (item.Description.Equals("euro"))   // check for determine  item.Description has contain "euro"
                {
                 /*code for when item.Description has contain "euro"*/
                }
              else
                {
                    /*code for when item.Description not contain "euro"*/
                }              
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just have to say this.

**This won't work:**

```cs
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Description))
```

**This variant will work:**

```cs
 if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Description)))
```